# @Assert\NotEqualTo() is not working

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities Candidate and ProgramType having a Many to One relationship

Candidate.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProgramType", inversedBy="candidates")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="program_type", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="lead.programtype.not_blank",groups={"registration","profile"})
 * @Assert\NotEqualTo("1",groups={"registration","profile"}) 
 */
public $programtype;
```

ProgramType.php:

```
/**
 * One ProgramType has Many Candidates.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Candidate", mappedBy="programtype")
 */
private $candidates;

public function __construct() {
    $this->candidates = new ArrayCollection();
 }
```

Problem is this line `@Assert\NotEqualTo("1",groups={"registration","profile"})`. The assert statement is not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: Does it work without groups?

Comment: no its not working without groups

Answer (score 0):

Your `programType` is on object of type `ProgramType`, thus "1" is a string, or a number... or whatever php wants it to be.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> $a != $b  Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type
>   juggling.

Then you are trusting php's type juggling.

You should instead do something like this, using [Expression validator](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Expression.html)

```
@Assert\Expression( 
    expression="this.programTypeIsNotEqualTo()",
    groups={"registration","profile"}
)
```

and implement

```
public function programTypeIsNotEqualTo() {
    return $this->programType->getId()!==1;
}
```

in your entity.

UPDATE: the Expression validator has been introduced in Symfony 2.4, so in 2.3 you could use the Callback validator, in the top of your entity

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(
 *    methods={"programTypeIsNotEqualTo"}
 *    groups={"registration","profile"}
 * )
 * @Entity()
 *
 */
  class XXXX {
  }
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I changed my entity to    ` /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProgramType", inversedBy="candidates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="program_type", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="lead.programtype.not_blank",groups={"registration","profile"})
     * @Assert\Expression( 
     * this.programTypeIsNotEqualTo(),
     * groups={"registration","profile"}
     * ) 
     */
    public $programtype;
    
    public function programTypeIsNotEqualTo() {
        return $this->programType->getId() !== 1;
    }`

Comment: But schema update gives me error `
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints
  \Expression" in property Epita\CrmBundle\Entity\Candidate::$programtype doe
  s not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
`

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 i'm sorry, i've edited the Assert in the response

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 do you have `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in the top of your entity?

Comment: which verison of symfony do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151274/discussion-between-ste-and-utkarsh2k2).

Comment: For this project I am using symfony 2.3